# Display date from mysql in flot chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, flot

I have an javascript array like this.

```
var daten2 = [["2016-02-13","35"],["2016-02-13","35"],["2016-02-14","27"],["2016-02-14","27"],["2016-02-15","21"],["2016-02-15","21"]];
```

I want to display this array with the flot library in a graph. The date should be on the x-axis.

```
var options = {

xaxis: {
     mode: "time",
     timeformat: "%Y-%m-%d"}
};
var plot = $("#placeholder").plot([daten2],options).data("plot");
```

The HTML part looks like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

However it is not working. Only one date is displayed. Its 1970, which seems like the default date. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the Flot documentation: "The timestamps must be specified as Javascript timestamps, as milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00." So, convert your X-axis date strings to Dates before calling `plot()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: convert the data you have to JavaScript dates for the X-axis.

```
var daten3 = daten2.map(function (element) {
  return [new Date(element[0]), element[1]];
});

$.plot("#placeholder", [daten3], options);
```